# mock service worker not working with axios post and payload

Tags: javascript, msw

I'm running into a weird problem. `Mock Service Worker` is not intercepting `axios.post` with a payload. Without the payload it works. For exmaple:

This works:

```
await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/test.json`);
```

This does not work:

```
await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/test.json`, { id: 1 });
```

by just adding `{ id: 1 }` MSW does not intercepts the call.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's been a known issue with intercepting POST requests. It should be fixed in the latest version of MSW (`0.43.1` by the moment of answering). Please update the package and follow the [release notes](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/releases) in case there are any breaking changes you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. (prev version 0.41.0)
**Please update latest version**... ssibure....